# How to prevent the people in Zoom from hearing the sound (e.g. Youtube) on my PC without headphone?

Tags: audio, youtube, zoom-meeting

When I attend a Zoom meeting, I still want to watch Youtube. But I do not want the Zoom people to know that I am watching Youtube, i.e. I do not want them to hear any sound from my PC. Is that possible? I only want my voice to be heard.

I know wearing a headphone can achieve this, but I do not want to wear a headphone.

Comment: I presume your computer does not have a modern array mic? If it does, there should be a setting to ignore background sounds, separate to any noise-cancellation in Zoom itself.

Comment: how do I know if I have this "modern array mic"?

Comment: Look up your laptop or [if separate] camera/mic spec t the manufacturer's site.

Comment: can you show me an example for a computer that has a modern array mic?

Comment: Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things:

(1) Press Mute in Zoom so you cannot be heard and so Windows sounds cannot be heard. This works for me. I do this to exclude extraneous noises in my office.

(2) Wear headphones for those times when you must be heard and cannot mute.

Possible workaround:  Play the You Tube on a different computer not near the Zoom microphone.  You will need to experiment. I have a TV (CNN) on low while using Zoom and I know people on Zoom do not hear it. As noted, you will have to experiment.

Comment: I said, I only want my voice to be heard. so (1) is not the solution.
I also do not want to wear headphone

Comment: So you will need to use headphones.  There is not any physical way to hear you but not the computer You Tube.

Comment: @ianselibai  -  I added a workaround for you to experiment with. Microphone pick up drops off rapidly so it might work for you.